# presto sql: select the data that before or after a datetime

Tags: sql, select, presto

There is table called t1, and there are columns id, created_at, text, for example, as following table:

```
id                created                      text
1       Thu Jun 30 01:00:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie1
2       Thu Jun 30 02:59:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie2
3       Thu Jun 30 03:49:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie3
4       Thu Jun 30 04:59:50 +0000 2016        I like this movie4
5       Thu Jun 30 05:39:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie5
6       Thu Jun 30 06:39:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie6
7       Thu Jun 30 06:29:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie6
8       Thu Jun 30 07:09:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie7
9       Thu Jun 30 07:39:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie8
10       Thu Jun 30 08:39:57 +0000 2016       I like this movie9
11      Thu Jun 30 09:39:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie10
12      Thu Jun 30 10:29:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie11
13      Thu Jun 30 11:29:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie12
12      Thu Jun 30 12:29:57 +0000 2016        I like this movie13
```

I want to select data separated by hour time.
For example, I want to select all the data that hour is less or equal 06, then I want to select the data that hour is more than 07. Since the data of column is datetime form: Thu Jun 30 12:29:57 +0000 2016, I don't know how to deal with this. Thanks for your help!

The sql is presto(presto sql):

```
select id, created, text from t1 where created_at <= 6
```

Comment: Please specify the rdms (mysql, mssql, oracel)

Comment: Adjust some of the created values to other dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it, use the hour(datestamp)can solve it.

```
select id, created, text from t1 where hour(created_at) <= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use datepart for this if you are using mssql:

```
select 
   id, 
   created, 
   text 
from 
   t1 
where 
   datepart(hour, created) <= 6
```

References:

- [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your comments, but presto has no datepart function.